# jQuery binding events within an event listener

Tags: jquery, events

I have a link with a click event listener bound to it. On click it attaches a click event listener to the document, this time the event is namespaced so that I can easily remove it. Upon attaching the second event it is immediately fired. Why is this occuring? My best guess is that the event is still bubbling up the dom tree when the new event is attached to the document. Because of this it triggers both events. See the following [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/84wth390/).

HTML

```
<a href="#" id="example">Click Me</a>
```

Javascript

```
$('#example').on('click', function(e) {
    $(document).on('click.example', function(e) {
        alert('example event triggered');
    });
});
```

What I am trying to accomplish is that on clicking a button I insert a dom element. When it is inserted I want to attach an event listener to the document that when triggered checks the event target in order to detect if any click events occur outside of the inserted element. If the target is within it it should do nothing. If the target is anywhere outside of the element it should hide the element.

Comment: on every click on #example you will bind a "$(document).on" this is somehow very strange and in my opinion wrong

Comment: In the given example you are correct, it would do so. In my actual code there is a check being run to determine if there is already an event listener in place if so it does not re-attach. Upon clicking outside of the created element the event is then unbound using off.

Comment: why don't you just bind the event in your "init method"? This way it will bind only once -- instead of making your life a bit harder to check things on runtime

Comment: I haven't been able to determine an easy way to do so in this instance because the code inside the listener is changing each time. I may just have been staring at this for too long. Time to take a step back and reevaluate in the morning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because of event propagation

```js
$('#example').on('click', function(e) {
  $(document).on('click.example', function(e) {
    alert('example event triggered');
  });
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="example">Click Me</a>
```

You are registering the handler when the event is still in the `anchor` element, and the event is bound to the document object which is a ancestor of the current element. So now when the event is eventually propagated and reaches the `document` object it will find the click handler bound to it and will trigger it.

Note: You should not just add new handlers in every click... hopefully you have taken care of it